# Apache always serving DocumentRoot index.php

Tags: php, apache

This might be a newbie question but... I configured a SSL site in Apache as follows:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName dev.wonnova.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/myapp/wwwroot"

    SSLEngine on

    SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1 +SSLv3
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:+SHA1:+MD5:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mycert.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mycert.key

    <IfModule mime.c>
        AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert      .crt
        AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl         .crl
    </IfModule>

    Alias /mydir/ "/var/www/myapp/mydir"

    <Directory "/var/www/myapp/mydir">
        SSLRequireSSL
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The thing is that no matter which URL I request, I always get the contents of /var/www/myapp/wwwroot/index.php (i.e. index.php in `DocumentRoot` directory).  It happens for these URLs, as an example:

```
 - https://mysite/index.php
 - https://mysite/mydir/index.php
 - https://mysite/mydir/style.css
 - https://mysite/mydir/script.js
```

On the other hand, if I create an index2.php file in DocumentRoot directory, it shows correctly:

```
 - https://mysite/index2.php
```

I guess there's something that is wrong with my Apache configuration.

Comment: Can you try `AllowOverride none` and give me results ?

Comment: do you have a `.htaccess` file in your root?

Comment: @Eray: nothing changed, :-(

Comment: @jaudette: nope, I have no .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue, I had to remove the last slash of the first part of the Alias line.

This was wrong:

```
Alias /mydir/ "/var/www/myapp/mydir"
```

This is right:

```
Alias /mydir "/var/www/myapp/mydir"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can remove the apostrophes from the Alias (I think yours is right though). Change the  configuration of your main site:

```
Alias /mydir/ "/var/www/myapp/mydir"

    <Directory "/var/www/myapp/mydir">
        SSLRequireSSL
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

to:

```
Alias  /mydir /var/www/myapp/mydir
    <Directory /var/www/myapp/mydir>
         SSLRequireSSL
         Allow From all
         Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
         AllowOverride all 

     </Directory>
```

Also you need to go to /var/www/myapp/ and edit the .htaccess and change it to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /mydir/
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /mydir/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I assume you have a DirectoryIndex file (e.g index.php) in the /var/www/myapp/mydir to which the alias is pointed. Let me know if it works

Comment: I changed the config as you mentioned with no luck.  I think there should be a way to make it work with no .htaccess.  I have it working like that in my laptop (Mac OS X) but same configuration does not work in Ubuntu, which is what I described above